# The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. - {Ajax, jQuery, Laravel}

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to delete an image using a button click. I'm using jQuery ajax to send the post request to the back end and the back end is Laravel. I'm triggering the POST request when the button is clicked and I'm not using a form. I'm not sure if this is the correct approach. Any ideas/suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Here's my **html code**

```
<div class="deal-images-in-new-deal-modal" id="deal-images-after-uploading-section" style="display:flex; justify-content: center; padding:10%; flex-wrap: wrap;"> 
  <div class="new-deal-upload-image">                                 
    <img src="" width="150" height="150">                              
  </div>                             
  <div class="new-deal-upload-icon">                                 
    <button type="submit" class="btn delete_image_button" id="after_image_upload_0" value="151159">                                     
      <i class="trash icon" id="after_image_upload" style="color:red;"></i>                                 
    </button>                             
  </div> 
  <div class="new-deal-upload-image">                                 
    <img src="" width="150" height="150">                              
  </div>                             
  <div class="new-deal-upload-icon">                                 
    <button type="submit" class="btn delete_image_button" id="after_image_upload_1" value="151160">                                     
      <i class="trash icon" id="after_image_upload" style="color:red;"></i>                                
   </button>                             
  </div> 
  <div class="success-message">Test</div>
</div>
```

Here's the **JS script file**

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete_image_button',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   var image_id = $(this).val();


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/deals/delete-image/'.image_id,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("inside success fuction", data);
            html = "<div id='success-message'>The image id is "+data+"</div>";
            $('.success-message').replaceWith(html);
        }
    });
});
```

Here's the route in the Laravel Routes file
**Routes.php**

```
Route::post('deals/delete-image/{image_id}','MainController@deleteImages');
```

Here's the code laravel controller file

**MainController.php**

```
public function deleteDealImages($image_id) {
        \Log::info("inside deleteDealImages function in back end");
        return $image_id;
    }
```

I'm getting 405 status code with error response as

```
{
    "message": "The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\MethodNotAllowedHttpException",
    "file": "/var/www/vendor_portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/AbstractRouteCollection.php",
    "line": 117
}
```

I've tried many different ways but still keep getting this error. Can someone please help me with this scenario ?

Comment: try clearing caches (specifically route cache)  but this will get em all `php artisan route:clear && php artisan view:clear && php artisan config:clear && php artisan cache:clear && php artisan clear-compiled && composer dump-autoload`   You may also need the token  "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}", as aparam

Comment: @Cameron tried all these but still not working. Also, I'm triggering the POST request without using a form but when the button is clicked.

Comment: php artisan route:list   do you see your route in there?

Comment: also, are you on laravel 8? or 7 and below?

Comment: `url: '/deals/delete-image/'.image_id`,  in js should be ` url: '/deals/delete-image/'+image_id`  or a template literal syntax.    if you add `Route::post('deals/delete-image/{image_id?}','MainController@deleteImages');` a question mark after image_id in the route it will make the param optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your javascript code, in the ajax url section to concatenate string you should use "+" not "."

Your Code

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/deals/delete-image/'.image_id,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("inside success fuction", data);
        html = "<div id='success-message'>The image id is "+data+"</div>";
        $('.success-message').replaceWith(html);
    }
});
```

The code you should write

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/deals/delete-image/' + image_id,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("inside success fuction", data);
        html = "<div id='success-message'>The image id is "+data+"</div>";
        $('.success-message').replaceWith(html);
    }
});
```

Comment: If this answer is correct, can you upvote this answer

Comment: I tried upvoting but I am unable too since my reputation is less but I did accept your answer.